# Regex to match specific words - C#

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm looking for a Regex(C#) to match the words "ass" or "a**". That is if the input text contains the word "ass" or "a**" the regex should match. Kindly help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are writing a bad language filter using regex?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Regex.Match(@"\ba(?:ss\b|\*\*)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

The `\b` word boundary anchors ensure that you won't accidentally match on `assorted` or `bass`.

Comment: @Jimmy: I didn't see *that* coming :)

Comment: I would add an ignorecase. I don't think big ASS(es) are smaller problems than small ass(es) :-) And note that your regex will catch a**ault :-)

Comment: @xanatos: Yes, you're right. Hard to guard against the latter case, though. Maybe with `@"\ba(?:ss\b|\*\*\B)"`. Of course, you'd then still match `a**wipe` and other unpleasant words.